# Printing a variable with an iterable inside? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 20 matrices I want to print in succession.. Filter_1, filter_2,..., filter_10 is there a way in to iterate through each matrix  to print using a for loop increasing the filter number.. I can't seem to find a way to concatenate it and keep it a variable.

```
for i in range(20):
    print("filter" + str(i +1), ? Filter_(i+1)?  - what goes here?
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really have variable `filter_i` in memory, you can access it by

```
locals()['filter_' + str(i)]
```

However, don't. Make a list of your filters, and access it as `filters[i]`

Comment: No the program I was given has 20 filters and I wanted to write a single print statement to print them all so I don't have to write print(filter_1, filter_2, filter_3, filter_4........., filter_20)